# How to use return to output the result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF95v.png)
[Eample format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEd6V.png)
Write a Python class, Flower, that has three instance variables of type str, int, and float, that respectively represent the name of the flower, its number of petals, and its price. Your class must include an initializer that initializes each variable to an appropriate value, and your class should include methods for setting the value of each type, and retrieving the value of each type. Your program should be robust enough to handle possible inappropriate inputs.

How to use return function instead of print function to implement the above output? Please follow the above example format.

[Code](https://i.s.gzA.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMQtR.png)
Here is my own attempt. But I cannot get any output.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score -1):

[Test image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF95v.png)

just type print(result_one) as per the above screenshot you mentioned in question.

```
print(result_one)
```

for better answers do not put photo of error and code.
directly paste them

Comment: Thank u so much! But "print(result_one)" is not in the test sample given by the teacher. I am not sure whether it will affect my score.

Comment: I don't think print statement will cause any problem unless it is specified in sop, not to use print statement.
Try not to discourage answers unless they are wrong.